# Difficulties to change axis lengths of Axes in manim

Tags: python, axes, manim

I'm working with Python 3.8.11, with manim.
I would like to make sure that the x and y axis have the same lengths (I need orthonormal coordinates) with Axes.
However, I tried to change the x_length and y_length parameters and it did not seem to do anything.

1. How come these parameters do not do anything?
2. Is there a work around, or a better way to get orthonormal coordinates with Axes.
   Here is my simple test code:

```
class UR_Small_Orthonormal(Scene):
   def construct(self):
      axes = Axes((0, 2), (0, 2), x_length = 2, y_length = 2)
      axes.add_coordinate_labels()
      axes.to_edge(UR)
      self.add(axes)
      self.wait()
```

Here is the result: a centered big graph, instead of a small graph at the upper right

[image: result of code]

Comment: It seems that this issue exists for 3b1b's manim but not the community one.

Comment: With the latest community version, it will work: https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.coordinate_systems.Axes.html